# laravel rename lara_admin bundle name in url

Tags: bundle, laravel

I am using `lara_admin` bundle for my admin panel which is accessible under `msmohan.com/lara_admin` path.

I don't want to show the `lara_admin` in the url. So can anyone tell me is there any option for renaming the url link?

Answer (score 2):

When you install a module and register it, you set it up like with this configuration:

```
'lara_admin' => array(
    'handles' => 'lara_admin',
    'auto' => true,
),
```

When the bundle registers routes, it uses that `handles` key as the basis for the route. So in the bundle's `routes.php` file, you can see:

```
Route::get('(:bundle)/login', 'lara_admin::sessions@index');
```

See that `(:bundle)`? That tells Laravel to look up the `handles` key. So if you change your registration for the lara_admin bundle to:

```
'lara_admin' => array(
    'handles' => 'admin',
    'auto' => true,
),
```

It will now be at `/admin/login`, for example.

Comment: FYI: it won't keep working. The lara_admin bundle has all kinds of issues related to routing.